# How to update resources with patch method using OpenAPI correctly?

Tags: api, rest, swagger, openapi

I am learning OpenAPI recently, and would like to know the best practices.
Let's say I have a resource called `Person`, and it is defined in `components/schemas` as follows:

```yaml
Person:
  type: object
  required:
    - id
    - name
    - age
  properties:
    id:
      readOnly: true
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
    age:
      type: integer
```

I've made `id` readOnly because when I do `post` or `patch`, the ID will be passed as part of the URL. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

`name` and `age` must present when the client tries to create a new person using `post` method, or `get` a person, therefore they are defined as `required`.

My question is about `patch`: what if I only want to update a person's `age` or `name` independently? Ideally I would like to do something like

```
PATCH /person/1

{"age": 40}
```

However, since I've defined `name` as required, I can't do it. I can think of several solutions, but they all have flaws:

1. Remove the `required` restriction. But if I do that, I lose the validation on `post` and `get`.
2. Use a separate schema for `patch`, e.g. `PersonUpdate`, with `required` removed. Apparently that leads to redundancy.
3. When I do `patch`, I do pass all the fields, but for the ones I don't want to update, I pass an invalid value, e.g.

```
PATCH /Person/1

{"age": 40, "name": null}
```

And make all the fields `nullable`, and let the server ignore these values. But what if I do want to set name to `null` in DB?

4. I use `PUT` for update, and always pass all the required fields. But what if my data is outdated? E.g. when I do

```
PUT /Person/1

{"age": 40, "name": "Old Name"}
```

Some other client has already changed `name` to "New Name", and I am overriding it.

5. Like method 3, but I pass additional fields when doing `patch` to indicate the fields the server should care, whether using query parameters like `?fields=age`, or add it to the JSON body. So I can change the `requestBody` to something like

```
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              allOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    _fields:
                      type: array
                      items:
                        type: string
```

Then I can do this

```
PATCH /Person/1

{"age": 40, "name": null, _fields: ["age"]}
```

In this way, I can update `name` to `null` as well

```
PATCH /Person/1

{"age": 40, "name": null, _fields: ["age", "name"]}
```

This method seems can work, but is there a better or widely accepted practice?

Answer (score 13):

I came up with the following solution:

```yaml
Person:
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PersonProperties'
    - required:
      - id
      - name
      - age
UpdatePerson:
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PersonProperties'
PersonProperties:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      readOnly: true
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
    age:
      type: integer
```

`PersonProperties` acts as a simple collection of properties which make up a the person model. It doesn't specify any `required` fields.

`Person` re-uses all properties of `PersonProperties` and, in addition, specifies which one are required. `PersonUpdate` re-uses all properties of `PersonProperties` and allows for partial updates.

This solution still feels hacky. Also, it doesn't work for partial updates of nested objects and nullable properties.

(In fact, since the `id` is `readOnly`, you could also add `required: [id]` on `PersonProperties` and remove `id` from the `required` list on `Person`)

Answer (score 9):

By splitting the schemas up into multiple, composable schemas, we can layer the schemas on top of one another without repeating ourselves. We can even support removal of properties via PATCH by making optional properties nullable.

Example OpenAPI definition allowing partial updates via PATCH endpoints (validated):

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
  title: Sample API with reusable schemas and partial updates (PATCH)
  version: 1.0.0

paths:
  /customers:
    post:
      tags:
        - Customer
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/CreateCustomer'
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerId'
    get:
      tags:
        - Customer
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer'
                  
  /customers/{CustomerId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - Customer
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/CustomerId'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer'
                  
    put:
      tags:
        - Customer
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/CreateCustomer'
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/CustomerId'
      responses:
        204:
          description: Updated
          
    patch:
      tags:
        - Customer
      requestBody:
        description: Update customer with properties to be changed
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              allOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerProperties'
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    Segment:
                      nullable: true
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/CustomerId'
      responses:
        204:
          description: Updated

components:
  schemas:
    CustomerProperties:
      type: object
      properties:
        FirstName:
          type: string
        LastName:
          type: string
        DOB:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        Segment:
          type: string
          enum:
            - Young
            - MiddleAged
            - Old
            - Moribund

    CustomerRequiredProperties:
      type: object
      required:
        - FirstName
        - LastName
        - DOB

    Id:
      type: integer
      
    CustomerId:
      type: object
      properties:
        Id:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Id'
          
    Customer:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerId'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerProperties'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerRequiredProperties'
   
  parameters:
    CustomerId:
      name: CustomerId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Id'
        
  requestBodies:
    CreateCustomer:
      description: Create a new customer
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            allOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerProperties'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerRequiredProperties'
```

Adapted from: https://stoplight.io/blog/reuse-openapi-descriptions/